Curly brace expansion fails on bash, in Linux, when called from Python
Consider this curly brace expansion in bash:
for i in {1..10}; do
  echo $i;
done;

I call this script from the shell (on macOS or Linux) and the curly brace does expand:
$ ./test.sh      
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

I want to call this script from Python, for example:
import subprocess

print(subprocess.check_output("./test.sh", shell=True))

On macOS, this Python call expands the curly brace and I see this output:
b'1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n'

On Linux, this Python call fails to expand the curly brace and I see this output:
b'{1..10}\n'

Why does curly brace expansion work on the interactive shell (macOS or Linux) and when called from Python on macOS, but fails when called from Python on Linux?

Try for i in $(seq 1 10);do echo $i ;done or the BSD equivalent for i in $(jot - 1 10);do echo $i ;done

@AndreWildberg Yes, I know about the other for loop syntax alternatives; I was curious why this one failed.

{1..10} is a bash feature, it is not defined in POSIX sh.
It seems that subprocess.check_output("./test.sh", shell=True) invokes bash (or another shell which supports this feature) in the first example (macOS) and sh in your second example (Linux).
See:

https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC3009
Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess
Does the `shell` in `shell=True` in subprocess mean `bash`?


shell=True does not mean "run this file as a shell script". It means "let the shell interpret the given command line". So Python runs something like /bin/sh -c './test.sh', not /bin/sh ./test.sh.
The shell then runs ./test.sh (not knowing or caring whether it's actually a shell script). And then the kernel looks at the file, sees that it's a text file, and runs it through whatever shell has been configured in your operating system, probably /bin/sh. And as others have pointed out, plain sh does not support the {1..10} construct.
The solution is to add a shebang line to your script, to explicitly tell the kernel which shell you need:
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}; do
  echo $i;
done;

You should also remove shell=True because it has no benefit in this case.

I had missed that one indirection, however as far as I can tell, the same shell that is used to execute -c ./test.sh is also used to execute the contents of test.sh without shebang line.

These are not always the same. On Windows, Python will invoke the shell from the COMSPEC environment variable, probably cmd.exe. But it seems unlikely that cmd.exe will try to interpret the script as a Windows .bat file.
